# During update of an Azure Stream Analytics Job, I get HTTP 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: rest, azure, azure-stream-analytics

During an update of streaming jobs (via REST Api, we use the generic one that allows to update any kind of resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/updatebyid), I get 422 without any additional information. Could anyone help with identifying the problem ?

Comment: Also include the details about your URI parameters and request body.

Comment: Well, this cannot do, as its customer's data :( What I am trying to figure out is when Azure rejects an update to StreamingJob and returns 422, unfortunately cannot find anything in documentation

Comment: You could hide the sensitive information, just post the format of your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, although there is very little useful information in your question, I eventually reproduce your issue on my side.

[image]

The reason has been described clearly by the error message :

> PATCH of Inputs, Transformation, Functions, Outputs or Devices is not allowed using the Streaming Job level API. Please use the API for the corresponding resources.

This means you could not include the `Inputs`, `Transformation`, `Functions`, `Outputs`, `Devices` in your request body, because they are different resources form the `streamingjobs`.

**Solution**:

To fix the issue, just use the API for the corresponding resources as mentioed in the error message.

1.[Update Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/streamanalytics/stream-analytics-input#update) : `PATCH https://managment.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/{job-name}/inputs/{input-name}?api-version={api-version}`

2.[Update Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/streamanalytics/stream-analytics-function#update) : `PATCH https://<endpoint>/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/{jobName}/function/{functionName}?api-version={api-version}`

3.[Update Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/streamanalytics/stream-analytics-output#update) : `PATCH https://managment.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/{job-name}/outputs/output?api-version={api-version}`

4.[Update Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/streamanalytics/stream-analytics-transformation#update) : `PATCH https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/{job-name}/transformations/{transformation-name}?api-version={api-version}`

For more details, you could refer to [Stream Analytics REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/streamanalytics/).

**Sample**:

I test to *Update Input*.

```
PATCH https://managment.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/joywebapp/providers/Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/joyteststream/inputs/joyinput?api-version=2018-11-01
```

Request body:

```
{    
   "properties":{    
      "type":"Stream",  
      "serialization":{    
         "type":"JSON",  
         "properties":{    
            "encoding":"UTF8"  
         }  
      }  
   }  
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! Actually, when I analyzed our logs (we use a C# wrapper around the REST API), I couldn't see any messages describing the issue. Generally, we are not interested in updating any properties of a StreamJob, we just want to update tags. Unfortunately, there's no dedicated api for that, that's why we need to call get -> apply tags -> update. Thanks once more